# how to explode multiple columns into number of rows in java spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

this is my input

```
sno var1 var2 var3
1  a|b x|y p|q
2 a1|b1|c1 x1|y1|z1 p1|q1|r1
```

i would like to explode all columns into separate rows without disturbing the sno,  if I use explode multiple times,  i am getting duplicate rows

expected:

```
sno var1 var2 var3
1 a x p
1 b y q
2 a1 x1 p1
2 a2 x2 p2
3 a3 x3 p3
```

but i am getting as below

```
sno var1 var2 var3
1 a 
1 b
1 x
1 y
1 p 
1 q
2 a1
2 b1
2 c1
.....
```

how can i get it corrected.   I am looking for resolution in java spark.

Comment: It seems you made some effort, if you will provide your code for parsing, we could help you to modify it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it in the following way.

```
df = df.withColumn("var_arr",functions.explode(functions.arrays_zip(
functions.split(df.col("var1","\\|"),
functions.split(df.col("var2","\\|"),
functions.split(df.col("var3","\\|")
)));

df = df.withColumn("v1", df.col("var_arr").getItem(0));
df = df.withColumn("v2", df.col("var_arr").getItem(1));
df = df.withColumn("v3", df.col("var_arr").getItem(2));
df.show();
```